# ansible-galaxy login: Unexpected Exception: No JSON object could be decoded

Tags: ansible, travis-ci, ansible-galaxy

I have been search all over and can't seem to solve this issue. I am trying to setup the Travis integration for the ansible role. According to the [docs](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/galaxy.html#authenticate-with-galaxy) I need to authenticate first. I then run `ansible-galaxy login`, provide my github details and then:
`Unexpected Exception: No JSON object could be decoded`.

The traceback:

```
    File "/usr/local/bin/ansible-galaxy", line 85, in <module>
    sys.exit(cli.run())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible/cli/galaxy.py", line 152, in run
    self.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible/cli/__init__.py", line 99, in execute
    fn()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible/cli/galaxy.py", line 553, in execute_login
    galaxy_response = self.api.authenticate(github_token)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible/galaxy/api.py", line 119, in authenticate
    data = json.load(resp)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.10_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 290, in load
    **kw)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.10_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 338, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.10_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 366, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.10_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 384, in raw_decode
    raise ValueError("No JSON object could be decoded")
ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded
```

I even tried to reinstall ansible but no luck. 
Any ideas?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This feature was not implemented yet in earlier versions of ansible galaxy. If you update to the latest version of ansible: [v2.0.0.2](https://releases.ansible.com/ansible/ansible-2.0.0.2.tar.gz) your issue should be resolved.